# Can't access BIOS on Samsung Slate XE700T1A

Tags: boot, bios, tablet, slate

When I turn on the tablet, I always get a screen for "SAMSUNG" but then:

> Windows Recovery Environment.  Your PC needs to be repaired.  A
>   required device isn't connected or can't be accessed.  Error Code
>   0xc0000185.  Your PC doesn't have the Windows Recover Environment
>   installed. ...

Any attempt to access BIOS (Holding Win Key while turning on or holding Volume Key while turning on) fails to produce any results, although sometimes this does result in a split second screen that says "Windows Devolper Preview.  Preparing automatic repair", but then continues to the Error screen.

I'm attempting to get into the BIOS to turn on the boot order to boot to USB first so I can overwrite the OS.

Is this thing a brick now?

Comment: Did you run a developer preview version of Windows before the issue started to occur?

Comment: @alljamin - This is a hand-me-down so I didn't get much info (I can ask if I need to). But since it says Windows Developer Preview I assume that yes, it was a preview of Windows 8 installed on top of Windows 7.

Comment: Holding the Windows button down while powering up worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I will have to send it in to Samsung for them to reset the bios, thus disabling fast boot.  There is apparently nothing I as a user can do unless I want to attempt breaking it open and resetting it myself.

Since this is a hand-me-down and probably out of warranty, I doubt Samsung will touch it and that makes it an expensive brick :(

Comment: A note on accessing BIOS, I'm not sure what the key combinations are, but try to press them, then press the power button while holding the key combination.

Comment: I tried again after 2 years and found that if you hold the UP + DOWN volume buttons while turning it on you go to BIOS.  You can't "change the boot order", but from BIOS you can launch where you want to boot from for the session.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same BIOS entrance problem so many times.
The problem is Windows has fast startup option to reduce the time it loads OS.

To do this it overwrites legacy Options in BIOS.so you cannot enter BIOS with old key combinations also you have limited time to press hot key.

`Default hot keys are Del + F8 , Or Del+F10 or Del + Esc or Del with something`

Windows button is not usually used to enter bios, but for the Samsung slate, which has no keyboard, the windows button is used to enter the bios. Immediately after turning the power on, depress the windows button and hold it down until the bios pops up. Then you can navigate in the bios using the volume buttons, the lock button (next to power button) as enter, and the windows button as esc.

Comment: I don't think it's enabling the USB during the boot so I can't use a USB keyboard in that case.  I tried those interrupt keys anyway and nothing worked

Comment: Actually peripherals are powered with BIOS. If you can use it in the error screen you get , you must be able to use it before OS loads. The Problem is sth different I Guess. Sorry I couldn't be any part of help.